# Music files do not play in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, howler.js

## Goal

Users play music on a shiny app

## Code

I am trying to use the [Shiny `howlerjs` extension](https://github.com/ashbaldry/howler) to let users play music on a shiny app. Following is an example from the package repo that plays fine:

```
library(shiny)
library(howler)

audio_files_dir <- system.file( "examples/_audio", package = "howler")
addResourcePath("sample_audio", audio_files_dir)
audio_files <- file.path("sample_audio", list.files(audio_files_dir, ".mp3$"))


ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "howler Example",
  useHowlerJS(),
  
  h3("Howler Example"),
  howlerPlayer("sound", audio_files),
  howlerSeekSlider("sound"),
  howlerPreviousButton("sound"),
  howlerBackButton("sound"),
  howlerPlayPauseButton("sound"),
  howlerForwardButton("sound"),
  howlerNextButton("sound"),
  howlerVolumeSlider("sound"),
  tags$br(),
  tags$br(),
  tags$p(
    "Track Name:",
    textOutput("sound_track", container = tags$strong, inline = TRUE)
  ),
  tags$p(
    "Currently playing:",
    textOutput("sound_playing", container = tags$strong, inline = TRUE)
  ),
  tags$p(
    "Duration:",
    textOutput("sound_seek", container = tags$strong, inline = TRUE),
    "/",
    textOutput("sound_duration", container = tags$strong, inline = TRUE)
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$sound_playing <- renderText({
    if (isTRUE(input$sound_playing)) "Yes" else "No"
  })
  
  output$sound_duration <- renderText({
    sprintf(
      "%02d:%02.0f",
      input$sound_duration %/% 60,
      input$sound_duration %% 60
    )
  })
  
  output$sound_seek <- renderText({
    sprintf(
      "%02d:%02.0f",
      input$sound_seek %/% 60,
      input$sound_seek %% 60
    )
  })
  
  output$sound_track <- renderText({
    req(input$sound_track)
    sub("\\.\\w+$", "", basename(input$sound_track))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The `audio_files` contain the sample files that the package author provided:

```
> file.path("sample_audio", list.files(audio_files_dir, ".mp3$"))
[1] "sample_audio/80s_vibe.mp3"    "sample_audio/rave_digger.mp3"
[3] "sample_audio/running_out.mp3"
```

## Problem

I make just 1 change. I replace the `audio_files` code with a path to my audio files as follows:

```
audio_files <- list.files(path = "Music/", pattern= ".mp3$", full.names = TRUE)

> list.files(path = "Music/", pattern= ".mp3$", full.names = TRUE)
[1] "Music/l1.mp3" "Music/l2.mp3" "Music/l3.mp3"
```

Everything else remains the same. The app opens without any error/warning. But the new music files do not play. Two questions:

1. What am I doing wrong in the above code that my local audio files do not play in the app but do play externally?
2. Please recommend other user-interfaces for selecting music within shiny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use music from the new directory, you will also need to change `addResourcePath` to the relevant path. In this case, if you use `addResourcePath("Music", "Music")` this should be enough for it to work.

Comment: Thank you so much for making this great library and answering my question. It works now.